# Retrieve a reference to a child element of a unknown data structure PHP

Tags: php

```
    if (!is_scalar($data)) {
      if (is_object($data)) {
        if (isset($data->{$key})) {
          //my logic here - unset($data->{$key});

        }
      } else {
        if (isset($data[$key])) {
          //my logic here - unset($data[$key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm having to do something like above which doesn't even take into account things like static properties on objects, and probably more edge cases, is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

By this I mean I want to have access to $data's child by $key so I can modify it, but I don't know what type of thing $data is

The last thing to consider is I'm changing $data by reference so creating a copy of $data->{$key} or $data[$key] means that the unset will fail on the original copy

Comment: Looks like you need to take a step back and look at what went wrong in your process / design before you came to the conclusion you have to end up with a workaround like above tbh.

Comment: Here is the full context: https://gist.github.com/slifin/816fca06028763e25d54fd16c92664aa basically I have a deep array a set of keys that are used to identify a part of the array and then I want to delete or change that part of the data structure, the solution uses recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($data) && !is_scalar($data)) {
 foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
   if ($key == $sub_iterator->key()) {
     // custom logic here like unset($value);
   }
 }
}
```

I think this will work on both arrays and objects just need to test